# Post-retirement plans for Ruby package in Precise 12.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, ruby

Now that Ruby 1.8.7 is [officially retired](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/), is it at all possible that the default ruby package in precise might be updated all the way up to 2.0?

I understand that backporting is generally not done with Ubuntu releases for concerns of breaking people, but in this case we're dealing with a deprecated package that might either already have security issues, or have more of them discovered in the future without any chance of them being fixed.

What's the plan? Will 12.04 march on with 1.8.7?

Comment: this should answer your question on this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/261329/package-for-ruby-2-0-on-precise

Comment: I saw that answer, however I wasn't sure if the policy listed there still applied to deprecated versions, hence this question.